# Understanding Recursion in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a simple recursive function and would like to understand why it results in an infinite loop. I thought it would terminate immediately because I'm passing in the number 0. But instead, it seems to pass through the if statement and recurse forever.

```
var rec = function(num){
  num = ee.Number(num)
  return ee.Algorithms.If(num.lte(0), 0, rec(num.subtract(1)))
}
print(rec(0))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ee.Algorithms.If](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-algorithms-if) is not designed to work this way (more information: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid_eealgorithmsif).

Consider the following:

```js
function doSomething(){
  print("hey")
  return 1;
}
var n=ee.Number(0);
var result = ee.Algorithms.If(n.lte(0), 0, doSomething())
print(result.toString())
print(result)
```

This prints:

```
hey
ee.ComputedObject({
  "type": "Invocation",
  "arguments": {
    "condition": {
      "type": "Invocation",
      "arguments": {
        "left": 0,
        "right": 0
      },
      "functionName": "Number.lte"
    },
    "trueCase": 0,
    "falseCase": 1
  },
  "functionName": "If"
})
0
```

On the client-side, ee.Algorithms.If builds a JSON representation of the instructions to send to the servers. You can see this by the `print(result.toString())` line. The instructions contain the condition, as well as the trueCase and falseCase. However, since you put a function inside the falseCase, it gets computed in the browser -- and thus we get the "hey" message printed in the console. Then the servers receive the JSON instructions, compute them, and return the trueCase to the client, so you get the value `0` from the `print(result)` (shortcut to `print(result.getInfo())`).

Thus, in your example, you never actually sent the instructions to the server because you got stuck in recursion within the browser (and you actually freeze the browser).

Comment: I see, great explanation. Wish I got that kind of explanation from GEE documentation. (or if it exists, it's not easy to find)